# Por qué mi proyecto de Laravel esta lento en Docker? (WSL2, Windows)

Tags: laravel, windows, docker, wsl, vite

soy nuevo usando Docker, actualmente estoy haciendo un curso de Laravel sobre Docker, y realmente no me causa problemas al correrlo, pero cada vez que se refresca mi navegador carga un poco lento, alguien me podría el explicar por qué sucede esto?

Que tengan un excelente día.

Answer (score 1):

Me pasaba exactamente lo mismo, lo que hice fue leer este post https://superuser.com/questions/1561465/docker-on-hyper-v-vs-wsl-2 y cambie wls a Hyper-V, me funciona muy bien.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, lo pondré en practica, tenga un buen día.